# Execute a Python script after a successful "Rebuild Project" in Android Studio

Tags: android, python, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I need to copy the newly generated apk to a remote machine, so currently I have an icon on the desktop which triggers a Python script.

I want this script to be invoked automatically by Android Studio after rebuilding the project was successful.

How can I do that?

I've found a snippet of code, specifically:

```
task generateSources << {
    def script = "python downloadAPK.py".execute()
}

gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    compileJava.dependsOn(generateSources)
}
```

but Android Studio complains about "Could not find method leftShift()..." when I insert this at the bottom of the app's `build.gradle`

Answer (score 1):

**This no longer works in Android Studio 3.5**

In the *build.gradle* file of the *app* Module add the following:

```
android {
    ...        
    defaultConfig {
      ...
    }    
    buildTypes {
      ...
    }    
    afterEvaluate {
        task upload_apk() {
            doLast {
                def do_upload = true
                if (project.hasProperty('android.optional.compilation')) {
                    if (project.property('android.optional.compilation').toString().contains("INSTANT_DEV")) {
                        do_upload = false
                    }
                }
                if (do_upload) {
                  println('\nUploading APK...')
                  exec {
                      workingDir "C:\\Users\Username\Desktop\\tools"
                      executable "python"
                      args "C:\\Users\Username\Desktop\\tools\\upload_apk.py"
                  }
                }
                else {
                    println 'Will not upload the APK since Instant Run has not modified it'
                }
            }
        }
        assembleDebug.finalizedBy(upload_apk)
    }
}
```